# How can I execute a custom app for NuttX with minicom?

Tags: button, stm32, led, nuttx

I wrote my first application for NuttX. I want it to read the state of a button and if its pressed the LED should light up for 1 second. I am using a self created board from a company with a STM32F103 on it.
I can activate the app via menuconfig. Then I compile the code and flash the Firmware on the board. I thought if I now open minicom I should be able to execute the app but it isnt possible. What did I do wrong?
Also I dont think all of my code is correct. I would appreciate if you could help me there also :)

All my files are:

- Make.defs

```
include $(wildcard $(APPDIR)/BeispielApp/*/Make.defs)
```

- Makefile

```
MENUDESC = "Beispiel App"

include $(APPDIR)/Directory.mk
```

- BeispielLED.c

```
/****************************************************************************
 * Included Files
 ****************************************************************************/

#include <nuttx/config.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <debug.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <nuttx/arch.h>
#include <nuttx/board.h>
#include <arch/board/board.h>

#include "stm32_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f103_minimum.h"

#include "chip.h"
#include "stm32.h"

/****************************************************************************
 * Private Data
 ****************************************************************************/

/* Pin configuration for each STM32F3Discovery button.  This array is indexed
 * by the BUTTON_* definitions in board.h
 */

static const uint32_t g_buttons[NUM_BUTTONS] =
{
  GPIO_BTN_USER1, GPIO_BTN_USER2, GPIO_BTN_USER3,
};

/* This array maps an LED number to GPIO pin configuration */

static const uint32_t g_ledcfg[BOARD_NLEDS] =
{
  GPIO_LED1,
};

/****************************************************************************
 * Public Functions
 ****************************************************************************/

static bool g_buttonPressed = false;

static void button_isr(int irq, void *context, void *arg) {
    g_buttonPressed = true;
}

/****************************************************************************
 * BeispielLED_main
 ****************************************************************************/

int main(int argc, FAR char *argv[]) {
    // Initialisiere GPIOs für Button und LED
    stm32_configgpio(g_buttons[i]);
    stm32_configgpio(g_ledcfg[i]);

    // Registriere den Interrupt-Handler für den Button
    irq_attach(NUM_IRQBUTTONS, button_isr, NULL);
    up_enable_irq(NUM_IRQBUTTONS);

    printf("Warte auf Buttondruck...\n");

    while (1) {
        if (g_buttonPressed) {
            g_buttonPressed = false;

            printf("Button wurde gedrückt! LED wird eingeschaltet.\n");

            // LED ein- und ausschalten
            stm32_gpiowrite(g_ledcfg[i], true);  // LED einschalten
            usleep(1000000);  // 1000ms warten
            stm32_gpiowrite(g_ledcfg[i], false); // LED ausschalten
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- BeispielLED Makefile

```
include $(APPDIR)/Make.defs

# Beispiel LED built-in application info

PROGNAME = $(CONFIG_BEISPIEL_APP_BEISPIEL_LED_PROGNAME)
PRIORITY = $(CONFIG_BEISPIEL_APP_BEISPIEL_LED_PRIORITY)
STACKSIZE = $(CONFIG_BEISPIEL_APP_BEISPIEL_LED_STACKSIZE)
MODULE = $(CONFIG_BEISPIEL_APP_BEISPIEL_LED)

# Beispiel LED

MAINSRC = BeispielLED.c

include $(APPDIR)/Application.mk
```

- Kconfig

```
#   
# For a description of the syntax of this configuration file,
# see the file kconfig-language.txt in the NuttX tools repository.
#

config BEISPIEL_APP_BEISPIEL_LED
        tristate "Beispiel LED App"
        default n
        ---help---
                Enable the Beispiel LED App

if BEISPIEL_APP_BEISPIEL_LED

config BEISPIEL_APP_BEISPIEL_LED_PROGNAME
        string "Program name"
        default "Beispiel_LED"
        ---help---
                This is the name of the program that will be used when the NSH ELF
                program is installed.

config BEISPIEL_APP_BEISPIEL_LED_PRIORITY
        int "Beispiel LED task priority"
        default 100

config BEISPIEL_APP_BEISPIEL_LED_STACKSIZE
        int "Beispiel LED stack size"
        default DEFAULT_TASK_STACKSIZE

endif
```